# accurately check if user is using TWA

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to recognize if user is using the **TWA** app or not.

simple solution is to check if:

```
document.referrer.includes('android-app://<com.package.app>')
```

But this is not working if you reload a page or open a page via another one. So I want a better solution.

We know if you run a link like this outside of the TWA app :

```
'example://check-app?action=check'
```

it returns an error:

> Failed to launch 'example://check-app?action=check' because the scheme
> does not have a registered handler.

I think if we can catch this error we can recognize if user is using TWA or not. So I wrote this:

```
try {
    window.location.href = 'example://check-app?action=check'
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

But it does't triger the catch at all.

is there any way to catch this error or check acuratly if user is using a TWA app.

Note: using `sessionStorage` is not a ideal way to do this. and you know why right?

Comment: Assigning to `location.href` always succeeds as far as javascript is concerned. You won't be able to detect url handlers from a web page.

Comment: JavaScript seems far from being a real programming language really... it shows us the error we can't catch!! this is ridiculous isn't it ?

Comment: That's not a javascript-generated error.

Comment: I see it as an error in a the console just as any other errors.. and of  course you should be able to catch this kind of things ...